# How can I retrieve that response in android using Volley library in android and Java

Tags: java, android

#### all data from API

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "Exercitationem perspiciatis quae ab facilis ratione quo.",
        "description": "ut",
        "amount": 6,
        "user": "Colten Paucek",
        "date": "2020-09-25T12:34:01.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": "Odit non nostrum possimus.",
        "description": "facere",
        "amount": 6,
        "user": "Colten Paucek",
        "date": "2020-09-25T12:34:01.000000Z"
    }
]
```

Above data are API response and I Want to get those data using Volley library in java android

#### My Java codes

The codes below are the java method which fetches data from my API

```
private void loadExpenseFromApi(){
     StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.EXPENSE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {
             try {
                 JSONObject jo = new JSONArray(response);
                 for(int i=0; i< jo.length(); i++) {
                     ListExpenses le = new ListExpenses(
                             jo.getInt("id"),
                             jo.getString("category"),
                             jo.getString("description"),
                             jo.getInt("amount"),
                             jo.getString("date")
                     );
                 }

             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             error.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

     );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced   `StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.EXPENSE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {` with a class called JsonArrayRequest to call the API
 `JsonArrayRequest jar = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.EXPENSE_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {`

#### Full codes looks like this

```
private void loadExpenseFromApi(){

     JsonArrayRequest jar = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.EXPENSE_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
             try {
                 for(int i=0; i< response.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
                     ListExpenses le = new ListExpenses(
                             jo.getString("id"),
                             jo.getString("category"),
                             jo.getString("description"),
                             jo.getString("amount"),
                             jo.getString("date")
                     );
                     listExpense.add(le);
                     adapter = new ExpenseAdapter(listExpense, getContext());
                     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                 }

             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
             error.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     );
     RequestHandler.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jar);
 }
```